# How are groups with the same Lie Algebra inequivalent?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I thought that groups with the same Lie Algebra are automatically equivalent, but there appear to be some exceptions to this?

What sort of exceptions are there and why?

Comment: What definition of "equivalent" are you thinking of?

Comment: Have the same group structure. Are the same group.

Comment: The additive group of real numbers and the multiplicative group of complex numbers of absolute value have isomorphic Lie algebras.  In general, Lie groups with isomorphic Lie algebras are locally isomorphic, but they need not be globally isomorphic.

Comment: What are the there situations where they are not locally isomorphic?

Comment: You need to assume your Lie groups are simply connected. Then you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3-sphere (unit quaternions) and SO(3)  have the same Lie algebra. Why? Because one is a double cover of the other, and the Lie algebra can be defined purely locally (via vector fields, for instance).

So I guess a general answer is "covering groups are a general case where same algebra doesn't (necessarily) mean same group."

(Sometimes you get a covering group that IS isomorphic, as in the covering $\theta \mapsto 2\theta$ on $S^1$.)

Comment: Do you believe there are other answers or does this answer exhaust all possibilities?

Comment: See Espen Nielsen's comment; that suggests that this is the only possibility.

Comment: Each (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra has exactly one simply connected Lie group associated to it (up to isomorphism). All other connected groups with the same Lie algebra are quotients of the simply connected one by discrete central subgroups. (See my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_, 2nd ed., Theorem 21.32 and Problem 21.18.)